# Diamond shape view

Tags: android, shapes, custom-view

I try to create diamond shape View. I want use it in popup. Does anyone have any idea how to do it ?

Thx for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [PathShape](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/PathShape.html): it looks like you can just pass it a Path with the right lines/fill and draw it on the popup Dialog's canvas.